# How to embed a video stream using django httpstreamingresponse

Tags: html, django

With respect to the Django view below, if I access it directly (no template) by going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/videostream`, which is the URL that points to `videoStream`, I will see a video stream of my webcam. How can I embed this stream into a webpage or template?

**views.py**

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        ret,image = self.video.read()
        ret,jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


def videoStream(request)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera())), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
```

My thought was that I could just do:

```
<video src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/videostream" autoplay="autoplay" >
```

or

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/videostream"
```

Both will make the request to the view, but the stream won't start.

**EDIT**
I sort-of have it working using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Webcam</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <img id="image">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        function refresh() {
           image.src = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/videostream/";
           image.onload= function(){
               setTimeout(refresh, 30);
          }
        }
        refresh();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this will start the feed but then crash after about 10 seconds because this is just making the request over and over every 30 milliseconds which I don't think httpstreamingresponse is meant for.

Comment: Don't know much about streaming video. One thing I notice is that there's a typo in the content-type: "multipart" should have one "p" only.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! That happened when I was transferring the code, so that error was not in the actual code. I have fixed it.